# How to separate model errors from measurement errors?

Tags: modeling, measurement-error, rms

I've got data measured with errors that have known measured_RMS. I am testing a model that has model_RMS differences between model prediction and measured data. What would be a reasonable estimate of model accuracy? That is, how do I separate what portion of model_RMS is due to model inadequacy and which is caused by measurement errors?